# Difference between InputFilterAwareInterface and InputFilterProviderInterface in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate, zend-inputfilter

Can someone explain me the difference between both interfaces InputFilterAwareInterface and InputFilterProviderInterface? Both seem to serve to the same purpose, to get an InputFilter, but I know they cannot be the same... And when do they get called?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both interfaces exist for different purposes. The [InputFilterAwareInterface](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/InputFilterAwareInterface.php) guarantees that implemented classes will have a `setInputFilter()` and `getInputFilter()` methods which accept and return an [InputFilter](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/InputFilter.php) instance when necessary. On the other hand, the [InputFilterProviderInterface](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/InputFilterProviderInterface.php) guarantees only that implemented classes will have a `getInputFilterSpecification()` method which returns a filter specification (configuration array) which is ready to use as argument in various input factories.

For example; the snippet below came from `Zend\Form\Form.php` class:

```
if ($fieldset === $this && $fieldset instanceof InputFilterProviderInterface) {
    foreach ($fieldset->getInputFilterSpecification() as $name => $spec) {
        $input = $inputFactory->createInput($spec);
        $inputFilter->add($input, $name);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Form class creates inputs and binds them to related filter using given specification which is returned by `getInputFilterSpecification()` method of the implementing class ($fieldset int this case).

**Using Traits**

Zend Framework 2 also provides lot of traits for commonly used interfaces. For example [InputFilterAwareTrait](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/InputFilter/InputFilterAwareTrait.php) for InputFilterInterface. This means, you can easily implement that interface if you have PHP >= 5.4

```
namespace MyNamespace;

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

MyClass implements InputFilterInterface {

    // Here is the trait which provides set and getInputFilter methods
    // with a protected $inputFilter attribute to all MyClass instances.

    use \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareTrait;

    // Your other methods.
    ...
}
```

Now anywhere in your code, you can do this:

```
$myClass->setInputFilter($AnInputFilterInstance);
$myClass->getInputFilter(); // Returns an inputfilter instance.
```

As you can imagine, no trait exists for InputFilterProviderInterface because its responsibility is only returning a valid config spec. It doesn't deal with any instance or class attribute like is forced in InputFilterInterface.